# Localization of a ring vs. localization of a module

Tags: commutative-algebra, localization

Let $A,B$ be (noetherian) domains and consider $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ a morphism of rings. This map endows $B$ with an $A$-algebra structure. Consider the induced map $\psi: \mathrm{Spec}\,B \rightarrow \mathrm{Spec}\,A$ between the prime spectra: I can study $\mathrm{Spec}\,B$ by considering the fibers of this map. Let $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ be a prime ideal and take $\mathfrak{q} \in \psi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$, i.e. $\mathfrak{q}\subset B$ is a prime ideal such that $\phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{q}) = \mathfrak{p}$.

I can localize $B$:

- As an $A$-module, obtaining $B_\mathfrak{p} := A_\mathfrak{p} \otimes_A B\,$;
- As a ring, obtaining $B_\mathfrak{q}\,$.

I'm trying to understand if there's some relation between these two rings. In particular I'm interested in a relation, if any, betweeen the residue field $\mathcal{k}(\mathfrak{q}) := \dfrac{B_\mathfrak{q}}{\mathfrak{q}B_\mathfrak{q}}$ and the quotient $\dfrac{B_\mathfrak{p}}{\mathfrak{p}B_\mathfrak{p}}\cong B \otimes_A \dfrac{A_\mathfrak{p}}{\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}}$.

If there's no general relation between these two localizations, is there any particular case in which there is some relation? I think I have proven that if $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}$ are maximal then the two $A$-modules are isomorphic since:
$$\dfrac{B_\mathfrak{q}}{\mathfrak{q}B_\mathfrak{q}} \cong \dfrac{B}{\mathfrak{q}} \cong B \otimes_A \dfrac{A}{\mathfrak{p}} \cong B \otimes_A \dfrac{A_\mathfrak{p}}{\mathfrak{p}A_\mathfrak{p}}$$
but I'm not sure if they're isomorphic also as rings.

Comment: $B_{\mathfrak q}$ is a localisation of $B_{\mathfrak p}$. Note that, in general, $\mathfrak p B$ is not a prime ideal of $B$.

Comment: Also, $B_{\mathfrak p}$ is a localisation of $B$ as an $A$-algebra.

Comment: @bernard thank you for your comment. How is the localization of an $A$-algebra defined? I only know localizations of modules and rings. Is it simply the localization of $A$-module that "behaves well" with the $A$-algebra operations?

Comment: It's simply the localisation as a module, but it happens to be compatible with the structure of algebra on $B$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for this. So by your first comment it should emerge that there's no direct relation between the two quotients, or am I missing something?